# How do I find out my root MySQL password?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I just installed MySQL on Ubuntu and the root user can't log in :)

How can I recover or find out my password?  Using blank for password does not work.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You can reset the root password by running the server with `--skip-grant-tables` and logging in without a password by running the following as root (or with sudo):

```
# service mysql stop
# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
$ mysql -u root
```

```sql
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("YOUR-NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

```
# service mysql stop
# service mysql start
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Now you should be able to login as root with your new password.

It is also possible to find the query that reset the password in `/home/$USER/.mysql_history` or `/root/.mysql_history` of the user who reset the password, but the above will always work.

Note: prior to MySQL 5.7 the column was called `password` instead of `authentication_string`. Replace the line above with

```sql
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("YOUR-NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';
```

Comment: By the way, should I be using sudo with these commands like mysqld_safe ?

Comment: @Benjamin I did all the steps in your answer but I still get the Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' - any ideas why?

Comment: Hmm, let me try it locally, and I'll update the answer with anything I find.

Comment: This worked for me. Are you using the password you set in YOUR-NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD when you login after running the commands?

Comment: @Banjamin yes I set the new root password to just "password" without the quotes so it was hard to get it wrong.  Trying again lol.  Can it be something with permissions?

Comment: Also, I am getting this message "Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) utility, e.g. stop mysql mysql stop/waiting" - any ideas why that is happening?

Comment: Also, MySQL is running on port 9681 for me which I think is not typical.  Might that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Ah, that message is encouraging you to use `sudo service mysql start` and `sudo service mysql stop` instead of the older `/etc/init.d/mysqld [command]` syntax.

Comment: Is your query `update user set password=PASSWORD("password") where User='root';` or `update user set password=PASSWORD(password) where User='root';`? You have to have the quotes around password or it will just rehash the old `password` column from the table.

Comment: @Benjamin I used single quotes.  Now when trying to repeat the process you outlined I get this error: "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)" after the mysql -u root command, and the terminal just hangs.

Comment: In my case, I had to replace /etc/init.d/mysql [command] with sudo mysqld [command]

Comment: @moderns make sure you add `-p` to your command, or the MySQL client will assume you don't want to enter a password. Full command: `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: Note that you have to do all this logged in as root, or 'as administrator' in Windows. Otherwise (in Windows at least) it will appear to work but revert as soon as you disconnect from MySQL.

Comment: For  MySql 5.7:  UPDATE mysql.user 
    SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('MyNewPass'), password_expired = 'N'
    WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';

Comment: After trying all of this many times, and the `dpkg` approach below, and getting super frustrated that nothing worked (btw, I'm using 16.04 with `mysql-sever-5.7`), I noticed that mysql would accept my new credentials if I used sudo to connect.  i.e. `sudo mysql -u root -p`  Without sudo I get `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`.  I've never had to use sudo before, and I don't see it mentioned here, but after a frustrating hour that seems to be the solution.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the answer.

Comment: thank you a lot - worked smoothnessly for me (MySQL 5.7.17 on Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: @Matt same here. I've never had to use `sudo` before when using mysql and now I have to? I don't understand why I have to be the root linux user to access the root account in mysql. This sort of behaviour reminds me of postgresql a bit more.

Comment: For anyone only able to login as shell root, look at this https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: You also need to change the "plugin" field to allow connection : `update user set plugin="mysql_native_password" where User="root";`

Answer (score 25):

```
sudo mysql -u root
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

mysql -u root -p # and it works
```

Comment: This is the only solution which worked for me on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked for me. Author of the post should have specified his MySQL version. Mine is `5.7.27`.

Answer (score 20):

I realize that this is an old thread, but I thought I'd update it with my results.

Alex, it sounds like you installed MySQL server via the meta-package 'mysql-server'. This installs the latest package by reference (in my case, mysql-server-5.5). I, like you, was not prompted for a MySQL password upon setup as I had expected. I suppose there are two answers:

Solution #1: install MySQL by it's full name:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
```

Or

Solution #2: reconfigure the package...

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

You must specific the full package name. Using the meta-package 'mysql-server' did not have the desired result for me.  I hope this helps someone :)

Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/mysql.html

Comment: Thank you!  I kept trying `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server`, but that didn't work.

Comment: This succeeded but didn't ask me for a root password for mysql in Ubuntu 18.04: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7`

Comment: yup, also running 5.7 and the reconfigure does NOT ask for a root password...? What gives,  and what IS the default?

Answer (score 10):

MySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 required slightly different commands as recommended [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset).  In a nutshell:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
mysql -u root
```

And then from the MySQL prompt

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And [the cited source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset) offers an alternate method as well.

Comment: can you help and provide details on what following exactly does?

`--skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`

It was really helpful for me to tackle client request but i'd like to learn about it so i can asses risk. Thanks!

Comment: [`skip-grant-tables`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables) certainly requires caution since anyone with access to the server can access all of the schemas for the instance.  [`skip-networking`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-networking) is less of a problem I think but you should assess for yourself. If I'm trying to reset the root password without the current root password I consider myself in a security pickle already :).  Not sure if there is a more 'secure' approach.

Comment: I got this ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking

Answer (score 4):

**For RHEL-mysql 5.5:**

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop

/etc/init.d/mysql start --skip-grant-tables

 mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE User='root';
 mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
 mysql> exit;

mysql -uroot -pnewpwd

mysql>
```

Comment: You could be a bit more verbose in the answer. Please explain what the commands you suggest do.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the best way to set your root password : [Source Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04) Step 3 is working perfectly for me.

Commands for You

> 1. sudo mysql
> 2. SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
> 3. ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
> 4. FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
> 5. SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
> 6. exit

Now you can use the Password for the root user is '**password**'  :

> 1. mysql -u root -p
> 2. CREATE USER 'sammy'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
> 3. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sammy'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
> 4. FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
> 5. exit

Test your MySQL Service and Version:

```
systemctl status mysql.service
sudo mysqladmin -p -u root version
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm Mysql 5.7.13 to reset all I did was:

`$ sudo service mysql stop` To stop mysql

`$ mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` Start mysql

`$ mysql -u root`

Just like the correct answer. Then all I did was do what @eebbesen did.

`mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('NEW-password-HERE');`

Hope it helps anyone out there :)

Answer (score 1):

Under MYSQL 5.7, If you are using mysql for development purpose, just :

1.kill mysql :

```
$ sudo service mysql stop
```

2.start mysql under --skip-grant-tables mode:

```
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

and, further, you could try to change the user table under "skip-grant-table" mode, however I failed.

so, this is just a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution.

MySql 5.7 comes with anonymous user so you need to reconfigure MySQL server.

You can do that with this command

try to find temp pass:

```
grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

then:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

On this link is more info about mysql 5.7

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html

Comment: I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually very simple. You don't have to go through a lot of stuff.
Just run the following command in terminal and follow on-screen instructions.

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Comment: Bad answer. You don't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

some time its become hard to find any i tried everthing i could find on the internet. but i could find the mysql server password. i have another way to find it without any command.
first you need to install a app named: FileZilla [Download from here](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php)
open the app then:
you need to add your host name it can be the ip provide by the hosting server. also add password and port and click on quick connect.
paste `/etc/mysql` in remote directory and find the file named: `debian.cnf` right click and download it. after downlaoding search file in c drive open in notepad where you can see password and user name.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, thanks! The root mysql & phpmyadmin password lies in this file. I access it with the command `sudo vim /etc/mysql/debian.cnf`, and here we see `user` & `password` field having the values we need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a bit of an assumption here because I'm not sure. I don't think my MySQL (running on latest 20.04 upgraded) even has a root. I have tried setting one and I remember having problems. I suspect there is not a root user and it  will automatically log you in as the MySQL root user if you're logged in as root.

Why do I think this? Because when I do MySQL -u root -p, it will accept any password and log me in as the MySQL root user when I am logged in as root.

I have confirmed that trying that on a non root user doesn't work.

I like this model.

**EDIT 2020.12.19:** It is no longer a mystery to me why if you are logged in as the root user you get logged into MySQL as the root user. It has to do with the authentication type. Later versions of MySQL are configured with the MySQL plugin 'auth_socket' (maybe you've noticed the /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock file on your system and wondered about it). The plugin uses the SO_PEERCRED option provided by the library auth_socket.so.

You can revert back to password authentication if desired simply by create/update of the password. Showing both ways and options below to make clear.

CREATE USER 'valerie'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket;
CREATE USER 'valerie'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';