# MySQL Access Denied for user 'root'@'localhost' when installed without setting a password

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I installed mysql server on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (`mysql-server`). When prompted for root password, as shown in the attached image, I chose to skip (entered Enter).

[image]

But when finished installing, I can't run mysql with root user:

```
m1@alex:~$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

What's the issue here? I see some answers for setting password but I was following a tutorial (on the left half of the image posted and they do it successfully without the password and I'd like to do the same.) 
~

Comment: Maybe a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11216911/3305116

Comment: @vard I don't think it's related. I've freshly a installed Ubuntu setup and I haven't tempered with any domain names/addresses.

Comment: Did you tried "mysql -u root -p" and enter without a password?

Comment: @PrzemysławJagielski yes. same error: `m1@alex:~$ mysql -u root 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
m1@alex:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of missing sudo it seems..

I got the hint from Matt's comment on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683154/how-do-i-find-out-my-root-mysql-password?rq=1)