# Errors in my python code: Can't connect to MySQL server

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, error-handling

I was trying to run a python project located [**here**](https://github.com/vasanthkalingeri/CommercialDetection) which is for ad detection inside a video. I installed the required dependencies on my Ubuntu 16.04 (by running the `dependencies.sh`). I changed the `comdet.py` main part to account for my input file:

```
def test_recognize():

    #input_file_path = '../test/test.mp4'
    input_file_path = '../test/nadal-news.mp4'
    ad_det = ComDet()
    ad_det.recognize_ads_file(input_file_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #test_generate()
    test_recognize()
```

Based on the instruction, I just do `python2.7 comdet.py`. After a few dependencies and import problems, now it complaints about not being connected to the local SQL database:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)")
```

What is the problem?

I thought maybe I should run `start-server.sh` located in `src/web`, but that does nothing. I'm new to python.

**UPDATE**: I set a password for my mysql installation. And then I update the password in `comdet.py` as below. Plus, I have to manually create a database called `devaju` in mysql command line.

```
config.setdefault('database', {
                            "host": "127.0.0.1",
                            "user": "root",
                            "passwd": "root",
                            "db": "dejavu"
                            })
```

Now the program runs, but nothing happens. No prints, nothing. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you connect at all to your sql server like : `mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p`

Comment: Ummm, no. It asks for a root password.  I left it blank during installation, but it doesn't accept blank. Is there a default password.

Comment: Normally you set it when installing, you can find some solutions for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683154/how-do-i-find-out-my-root-mysql-password

Comment: Error `111` means `Connection refused`, better provide your connection string

Comment: are you using SQL lite or MySQL ?? i have checked the github project folder, looks like settings is pointing to sqllite but the dependency is pointing to mysql . which database are you using ?  if you are using MySQL, have you modified the settings.py file.

Comment: I just installed mysql as instructed. Sudo apt-get install python-mysql i guess.

Comment: @Sherry what do u mean of connection string? The code is already there.

Comment: updated the question!